# How Can I Slice the Three Middle Indexes of Any List?

Tags: python

I am trying to print the three middle indexes of any list in Python, but am having trouble figuring it out. I know how to find the three middle indexes on their own, but I can't seem to print all three in a list. Here's what I have so far.

```
print("Three items from the middle of the list are:")
middle = (int(len(numbers))/2)
middle_two = (int(len(numbers))/2) - 1
middle_three = (int(len(numbers))/2) + 1
print(list(middle + middle_two + middle_three))
```

Whenever I try to put `list()`around any of the integers or concatenate them, I get an error: "'float' object is not interable'. I know what that means in practice, but I am stuck on how to turn all three middle indexes into a list.

Comment: What you do when you have 4 items in the list? (or any other even number of elements)

Comment: "float object is not iterable" possibly due to not using integer division. Use // to divide numbers because indices must be int and you are getting float right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you last line you are adding your indices `a+b+c` and get a number, than you want to convert this `number` to a `list`, which results in an error:

```
list(9.0) # TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
list(9)   # TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

You need to combine the indices to a list:
with `[a, b, c]`:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = np.arange(10, 20)

print("Three items from the middle of the list are:")
middle = len(numbers) // 2  # ensure that your indices are integers
middle_two = middle - 1
middle_three = middle + 1
middle_list = [middle, middle_two, middle_three]
#             ^      ^           ^             ^
print(middle_list)           # [5, 4, 6]
print(numbers[middle_list])  # [15 14 16]
```

Comment: Ah, how did I miss that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler method than calculating these individually. You can simply find the middle of the list with `len(numbers)//2`. We do the `//2` to force integer division, which will return an `int`. This is critical because the float that comes out of `3/2`, which is `1.5`, is not a valid list index. This makes sense, as there wouldn't be a *'one-and-a-half-th'* item in a list.

On the other hand, `3//2` will return `1`, which *is* a valid index (remember, [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html))

Putting all these together in a function, we get this:

```py
def middle_three(items:list):
  assert len(items) >= 3, "middle_three needs at least 3 items in the input!"
  middle = len(items)//2 # find the index of the middle of the list, rounded down for even lists
  return items[middle-1:middle+2] # +2 because we want +1 from the middle, +1 more because of indexing syntax
```

We can try this out on some sample lists:

```py
for i in range(3, 20):
  print(i, ':', middle_three([*range(i)]))
```

> ```
> 3 : [0, 1, 2]
> 4 : [1, 2, 3]
> 5 : [1, 2, 3]
> 6 : [2, 3, 4]
> 7 : [2, 3, 4]
> 8 : [3, 4, 5]
> 9 : [3, 4, 5]
> 10 : [4, 5, 6]
> 11 : [4, 5, 6]
> 12 : [5, 6, 7]
> 13 : [5, 6, 7]
> 14 : [6, 7, 8]
> 15 : [6, 7, 8]
> 16 : [7, 8, 9]
> 17 : [7, 8, 9]
> 18 : [8, 9, 10]
> 19 : [8, 9, 10]
> ```